# ASP.Net Web Project Deploy with Database Migration at Different Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

Our solution contains (basically) 3 different projects.

- Web Api
- MVC
- DbCore
- Domain

Web Api and MVC projects are (as you can guess) web projects and DbCore and Domain are Class library projects.

DbCore contains Entity Framework definitions, configurations also migrations.

Web Api connects DbCore through Domain.
This infrastructure works well but i want to deploy and apply migration db while deployment. But deployment wizard doesn't show me option about that because web projects don't contain any DbContext definition.

How can i achieve this?